# Which query is not Buffered Internally with Split Query when MARS is disabled?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-mars

I was reading the [efficient querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming) microsoft article and there is a part which is unclear to me:

> When split query is used, the resultsets of all but the last query are buffered - unless MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) is enabled on SQL server.

To illustrate my question, let assume I have a code that creates 3 query:

```
var questionsStream = stackoverflowContext.Set<Question>()
    .Include(q => q.Statistics)
    .Include(q => q.Answers)
    .AsSplitQuery();

foreach (var question in questionsStream)
//...
```

Which table result is streamed?

- Question table,
- Answer table,
- random/depends on (what?)

If it is the last `Include()` I should order my Includes to have the possibly longest one at the end of the chain (to spare memory), right?

I searched SO for "*internal buffering*", "*split query*", "*ef streaming*", "*ef MARS*" and similar terms before asking the question. I found out what happens if MARS is enabled by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580890/why-is-assplitquery-doing-separate-roundtrip-to-db-for-each-query), but no answer to what happens when it is disabled.

Comment: Essentially, EF Core can't populate `question` until each `Include()` has been processed. But can `yield return question` while the last query result is being streamed.

Comment: If it's not explicit in the documentation, then there's no guarantee of any specific behaviour in future versions. Though you could dig into the implementation to work out how it currently behaves. (https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/2f63e73519275dc134c8df238a02f928720e2cf0/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.cs#L250).

Comment: I would guess it's a simple matter of examining the `QueryString` and looking for the last query that's executed, which will inevitably be the one that is not buffered.

Comment: I suspect the implementation lazily opens each result set. But if mars is disabled, and a result set is already open, the data is cached to allow the next result set to be retrieved. So the order would depend on how the query is compiled. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks much for the *Visitor* class hint! If the returned *Expressions* become query later on, and are executed in order, then I know at least the query order is constant. To reflect your 1st comment: It would be nice to have `Question`s streamed and navigation properties buffered but it seems `Question`s can populate anyway as 1st query. I assume EF does not care how the relations are referenced, e.g. yielded from a `DataReader`.

Comment: @Charlieface The queries were in Linq order: `select * from Question`, `select * from (select top(1) Id from question) inner join Statistics`, and finally the same with `Answers`. Kind of makes sense but I hope I'll get a more reliable source than what I can observe. Because that can be less than implementation details (less guarantee for query order).